# How To use @parent of blade to add li to ul

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I'm trying to use @parent to append li to ul to bulidbreadcrumb
this is my header code
(master.blade.php)

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
     @yield('breadcrumb')    
 </ul>

and this is my code in the view (index.blade.php)

@layout('layouts.default')

@section('breadcrumb')  
 <li> {{ HTML::link('','Brands') }} </li> @parent
@endsection
```

and this is the material i follow
http://laravel3.veliovgroup.com/docs/views/templating

@parent not work for me , i need help

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to have @parent in your layouts.default so it echos the parent content.

http://laravel.com/docs/templates

Answer (score 1):

```
@layout('layouts.default')

@section('breadcrumb')
  @parent
  <li> {{ HTML::link('','Brands') }} </li>
@endsection
```

@parent should be in a new line.

if you want that put @parent after, will work too.

```
@layout('layouts.default')

@section('breadcrumb')
  <li> {{ HTML::link('','Brands') }} </li>
  @parent
@endsection
```

I believe that @parent works in somewhere, but i tested only at begin and end.

```
@layout('layouts.default')

@section('breadcrumb')
  <li> {{ HTML::link('','Brands') }} </li>
  @parent
  <li> {{ HTML::link('','Brands') }} </li>
@endsection
```

If you want, Laravel 4 brought many improvements to blade template.

Sorry my bad english. I tried write better.

Comment: it's stated in the (L4) docs that `@parent` must come at first.

Comment: In laravel 3 i'm not sure, but in laravel 4, all ways above work for me.

Comment: I not find that '@parent' must come at first in laravel 4 docs: '@parent' allow you to append to the contents of a layout section. Local not specified.

Comment: you are right, @Lucas. i mixed it up in the docs, it does work.